# A computer unable to connect to the Internet, installed python prompt: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll missing, how to solve

Tags: python-3.x

Prerequisites: The computer cannot connect to the Internet (no internet access, do not attempt to connect to the Internet)

After installing `python3`, a `python.exe` error message pops up: `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing.` After searching online, it is reinstalled `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015`. , copy the installation file from other places, reinstall, still can not be solved, how to solve ah, the computer can not be networked, but you can download files from other computers to copy the past, but must ensure that the software package can be installed offline, no network can not be online Installed

From other sources, you must first install `Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu`, I can not download the package before installation, because I found this installation package is installed online, you need to connect to the network, how to download`Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu` Offline installation package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to fix "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing" error showing up in many games (and unability to install "microsoft visual C++ 2015" (or 2017) giving 0x********* unspecified error in windows without service pack installed). Install this program

https://code.visualstudio.com/

and copy all dll files from "C:\Users\Computername\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code" into game directory overwriting whats there (remember to make backup of all dll files before)

Answer (score 0):

"api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing" is a common error on Windows. This happens when the program isn't able to find the .dll file which is required in order for the program to run. In this case, this .dll file is missing from your computer.

You can fix this error with any of the below methods:

- By repairing "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015"
- By updating your Windows installation via settings
- Or you could download and install the redistributable manually from Microsoft: https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe.

You may opt for any of the above methods to fix this error on your PC.